# Is there an AndEngine Class Library?

Tags: android, andengine, class-library

I'm trying to use AndEngine for my computer science summative (which is to design a game for android) to make my life easier, since I'm pretty new to this stuff and am by extension bad at understanding the stuff in the official [Android Class Library](http://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html). I'm also having a hard time understanding the AndEngine Examples because I don't know what the parameters being passed into the methods are for. So I was wondering if there was something like the Android Class Library for AndEngine (or any similar documentation, really). And yes, I've looked for myself.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is this JavaDoc for AndEngine - it appears to be the GLES1 branch. I would consider it "unofficial" as I have not seen it referenced anywhere, but you may find this helpful

http://codetheater.com/andengine_javadoc/

Comment: Yes, AndEngine is suffering from lack of documentation, and this is community (actually - one person) project. Maybe, something will be different for GLES2 branch.

Answer (score 0):

There is this project to provide documentations for the andengine
https://code.google.com/p/andengine-doc/

also I recommend following some tutorials, there are bunch of them in the tutorials section
http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/

but if you wanna get something done pretty fast and actually have a working "game" try my tutorial here, gives you a simple start for using andengine to create a simple game
https://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/andengine-simple-android-game-tutorial/